# Сформировать единый список ДТО

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Добрый день, я работаю из Spring Data JPA и возникла такая ситуация.
Допустим в базе данных хранится информация про группу в университете(ид группы, название группы, направление и т.д.) - это 1 таблица. В таблице 2 хранится информация о преподавателях группы(имя, фамилия и т.д., ид группы). Также есть таблица 3, где гранится информация о студентах группы(имя, фамилия и ид группы).

Так вот, мне нужно вытянуть из базы информацию про группу в ДТО(название группы, КОЛИЧЕСТВО студентов в группе, имена преподавателей) и сформировать таким образом лист ДТО, чтобы его было удобно отправить на фронт-энд и там уже парсить эти данные.

Для этого решил использовать JPQL и таким образом формировать лист ДТО. В этом плане помогла эта статья https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/.

Но получилась такая ситуация, что когда джоинить все эти таблицы, то в листе получаем некоторые дто, в которых разными будут только имена преподавателей, а также некоторые дто будут просто повторятся. 
Вопрос заключается в том, а как этот лист обработать(без костылей) чтобы на выходе получить нужный лист дто.

Comment: Было бы хорошо увидеть таблицы, запрос и саму DTO.

Comment: Описание сущностей в студию...